# How to Vectorize 10million rows with for and if conditions in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance, vectorization

I have one row which one is full of Unix timestamp. I need to create a new row and label them as 'occured' if the timestamp falls into certain range. but i have 10 million rows to iterate.

my code:

```
`
start_time = 1.583860e+12 #example timestamp
end_time = 1.583862e+12
for i in range(0, len(df['time'])):
    if (start_time < df['time'][i] < end_time).all():
        df.loc[i, 'event'] = 'occured'
    else:
        pass `
```

the above code is running forever to process 10 million rows. i tried vectorizing but i could not do it as i dont have much experience. Can some one help me in this regard ?

Comment: kindly share sample dataframe, with expected output. share as text, not pics

Comment: Does `df['event']` already exist?  What `dtype`?  Looks like you want to keep the other values unchanged?

Comment: hi @hpaulj, df['events'] doesnt exist. it is created when the if conditions gets true. i want to keep the other values unchanges. basically am just marking the timestamps in the new columns as occured when my condition matches

Comment: I wouldn't use floating-point values for what are essentially integer timestamps.  Eg, use `1_583_860_000_000` instead of `1.583860e+12`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to use vectorized operations in pandas to flag values in the range:

```py
df.loc[(start_time < df.time) & (df.time < end_time), 'event'] = 'occurred'
```

We use vectorized pandas comparison and boolean operations (`<`, `>` and `&`) to populate the appropriate rows in the new `event` column.

Full test code is here:

```py
start_time = 1.583860e+12 #example timestamp
end_time = 1.583862e+12
import pandas as pd
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':random.choices(range(10), k=10000)})
df.time = df.time *1.0e6 + 1.583855e+12
df.loc[(start_time < df.time) & (df.time < end_time), 'event'] = 'occurred'
print(f"count of 'occurred': {sum(df['event'] == 'occurred')}")
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
count of 'occurred': 975
           time     event
0  1.583863e+12       NaN
1  1.583861e+12  occurred
2  1.583862e+12       NaN
3  1.583860e+12       NaN
4  1.583861e+12  occurred
```

If you prefer to have an empty string in rows without 'occurred', you can just initialize the `event` column in advance:

```py
df['event'] = ''
df.loc[(start_time < df.time) & (df.time < end_time), 'event'] = 'occurred'
```

Comment: is there a simple explanation why `.loc` outperforms `np.where` here ? I tested your code with `%timeit` and mine (`df['event'] = np.where((start_time <= df['time']) & (df['time']<= end_time), 'occured', '')`). I thought using numpy fasten things (usually) up compared to the pandas library

Comment: With `np.where(A,B,C)`, `A`, `B`, `C` are evaluated (in full), and then passed to `where`.  `where` just selects elements from `B` and `C` based on the values of `A`. Your `B` and `C` are strings, but `A` is a pandas Series.  And the assignment to `df['event']` is pandas.  So it isn't "pure" `numpy`.  Also a `Series` has at least 2 arrays - the values and the indices, so you can't simply say this or that is `numpy` or `pandas`.  The relation is complex